# Преобразование Bitmap ресурса в ImageSource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Имеется `Bitmap` ресурс `Properties.Resources.part1`. Нужно установить этот ресурс в свойство заполнения прямоугольника `Rectangle.Fill`. Но `Fill` свойство принимает только тип `ImageSource`

Comment: Как-то так: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9028808/3079266

Comment: @Mints97 ответы желательно оформлять отдельно, ссылку можно указать в качестве источника. Ответ при этом должен быть на русском языке.

Comment: На самом деле, ваш подход неверен. Почему у вас в WPF-программе специфичный для WinForms `System.Drawing.Bitmap`, а не специфичный для WPF `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage`? Вы сами создали себе проблему. Делайте правильно с самого начала, и всё будет работать из коробки.

Comment: Тогда другой вопрос: как правильно добавить изображение в ресурсы приложения, чтобы тип был BitmapImage а не Bitmap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваша задача имеет два решения:

На одно @Mints97 привел ссылку [Get ImageSource from Bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028781/get-imagesource-from-bitmap/9028808#9028808), выглядит оно так:

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap br = Properties.Resources.part1;
System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource b = 
    System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
           br.GetHbitmap(), 
           IntPtr.Zero, 
           Int32Rect.Empty, 
           BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
```

Но я бы не помещал рисунок в ресурсы, а поступил иначе:

1.Создал бы в проекте папку, например IMAGES;

2.Поместил ваш рисунок (part1) в эту папку;

3.Тогда бы код выглядел так:

```
System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage b = 
    new BitmapImage(
        new Uri("pack://application:,,,/IMAGES/part1.bmp"));
```

Ну и соответственно:

```
rectangle.Fill = new ImageBrush(b);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Сам пришел к такому варианту)